# Item not showing up in ListView after adding from another page - Xamarin

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

So I have a Tabbed Page with 2 pages on it. CurrentTasks and FinishedTasks. I have a button on CurrentTasks that adds a Task into a list that I have inside FinishedTasks. It's adding the task but I'm not able to see it in the list view.

This is the event handler that adds the new task into the list, which is on the CurrentTasksPage

```
    FinishedTasksPage f = new FinishedTasksPage();
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Models.Tasks newTask = new Models.Tasks { Name = "dsdsds" };
        f.FinishedTasklist.Add(newTask);
    }
```

And heres what the FinishedTasksPage looks like

```
  private ObservableCollection<Models.Tasks> finishedTaskList { get; set; }
    internal ObservableCollection<Models.Tasks> FinishedTasklist { get => finishedTaskList; set => finishedTaskList = value; }

    public FinishedTasksPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        finishedTaskList = new ObservableCollection<Models.Tasks>
        {
            new Models.Tasks {Name = "name"}
        };
        listView.ItemsSource = finishedTaskList;
    }
```

Comment: You create a new instance of FinishedTasksPage inside of your CurrentTasksPage, and you create a new instance of CurrentTasksPage inside of your FinishedTasksPage.  Without seeing the full code, I am guessing that you are creating too many instances of these classes (even though only one is visible), and you are adding the task to an instance other than the one that is displayed in your tab page.  Initialize both tab pages from the master page and make sure you are adding your tasks to that instance.

Comment: To update data on visual element, you must use Bind or set the updated list to your `listView.ItemsSource` on every change. I strongly recommend you to use Binds (and MVVM pattern, if possible)